# Python now thinks arguments are files: Broken emerge, pip, livestreamer and most tools using Python

Tags: shell, command-line, python, gentoo, emerge

For these commands (in both bash and fish):

```
sudo emerge eix
emerge eix
```

I get this error:

```
usage: emerge [-h] [--version] [input [input ...]]
emerge: error: argument input: can't open 'eix': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'eix'
```

Same thing with livestreamer (and "pip install"):

```
#~/temp> livestreamer http://www.twitch.tv/totalbiscuit
usage: livestreamer [-h] [--version] [input [input ...]]
livestreamer: error: argument input: can't open 'http://www.twitch.tv/totalbiscuit': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://www.twitch.tv/totalbiscuit'
```

If a file with the name of the first argument exists, I get the same error for the second argument:

```
#~/temp> emerge test eix
usage: emerge [-h] [--version] [input [input ...]]
emerge: error: argument input: can't open 'test': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test'
#~/temp> touch test
#~/temp> emerge test eix
usage: emerge [-h] [--version] [input [input ...]]
emerge: error: argument input: can't open 'eix': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'eix'
```

How to reproduce (not really):

1. Be me, happily coding on a dying keyboard (broken cable, sometimes results in me creating weird files in ~/).
2. *(maybe unrelated)* Do `sudo pip3 uninstall aiohttp_jinja2` in the process, because I don't need it anymore (wrapper for Jinja2 templating engine for aiohttp.web AsyncIO webserver).
3. Find out that pip, emerge and livestreamer don't work.
4. Find a weird empty directory /home/username/~/ (it was an actual directory ~/~/, not a pointer to ~/.), remove it out of frustration with `rm -r \~/`
5. Go to sleep after 10 hours of work.
6. Wake up, tools using Python still don't work after boot, find that ~/~/ directory is there again, remove it again.
7. Try to change primary Python version to 2.7 from 3.3 (`sudo eselect python set 1`), doesn't help.
8. Download https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/aiohttp_jinja2/aiohttp_jinja2-0.4.1.tar.gz and install it manually with `sudo python3 setup.py install`, that doesn't help (probably something still proken in core Python modules, maybe `os` or `configparser`, not sure.
9. Ask a question on http://superuser.com, realize it's too technical and Linux-related, ask here.

iPython is also dead in an interesting way (both ipython and ipython3):

```
#~> ipython
You are running chardetect interactively. Press CTRL-D twice at the start of a blank line to signal the end of your input. If you want help, run chardetect --help
```

**Any suggestions?**

**Update:** Getting closer.

So `/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python-exec/python2.7/emerge -av eix` works just fine, I think the problem is related to [python-exec2](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Python/python-exec) somehow:

```
#~> file /usr/bin/livestreamer
/usr/bin/livestreamer: symbolic link to ../lib/python-exec/python-exec2
#~> file /usr/bin/emerge
/usr/bin/emerge: symbolic link to ../lib/python-exec/python-exec2
#~> file /usr/bin/pip
/usr/bin/pip: symbolic link to ../lib/python-exec/python-exec2
#~> file /usr/bin/pip3
/usr/bin/pip3: symbolic link to ../lib/python-exec/python-exec2
```

Comment: Strange. Can you check that your PATH is about sane, and check that `/usr/bin/python` is a symlink to python-wrapper, and that python-wrapper is an executable (not a script)? Can you use `python2` and `python3` without issues?

Comment: @Mat PATH is `/bin /usr/bin /home/username/bin /home/username/bin` (twice because i'm bad at using .config/fish/config.fish, but that's not a problem, I've checked). Is that sane? my path under sudo -s is `/bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin /opt/bin`, but I have the same problem there. python-wrapper is an executable, and both python and python3 symlinks work fine (but not ipython). So it's probably only part of Python that is broken, some module?

Comment: Looks ok. This is very strange :-) Does `/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python-exec/python2.7/emerge` work?

Comment: @Mat it works, see the post update for details.

Comment: Yep, looks like it. The symlinks are ok, maybe that `python-exec2` file itself got borked somehow, have a look at it (or python-exec2-c, but that's supposed to be an executable). Can you try re-emerging `dev-lang/python-exec` maybe?

Comment: @Mat This fixed everything. Do you want to post it as an answer? This is what I had in `/usr/lib/python-exec/python-exec2` before: `# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'chardet==2.3.0','console_scripts','chardetect'
__requires__ = 'chardet==2.3.0` and I only had `dev-python/chardet-2.2.1` installed, so it seems that `pip` somehow replaced my system's `/usr/lib/python-exec/python-exec2`.

Comment: Same issue on Gentoo forums, seems to be a recurring problem with `pip`: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1006016.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The programs you're having trouble with are all run using the `dev-lang/python-exec` script wrapper, which appears to have been somehow corrupt.

To attempt to re-install that package, assuming nothing else was severely harmed, you can try (adjust the version number to match your installed packages):

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/lib/python-exec/python2.7/emerge -1a dev-lang/python-exec
```

If your python installation is also broken (or some other critical system package), you should be able to recover by using binary packages. You can download some from [Tinderbox](http://tinderbox.dev.gentoo.org/).

Depending on how badly the installation is broken, you might have to boot into a Live CD to download the packages and manually mount your filesystems to install the binary packages.

Comment: This worked. This is what I had in /usr/lib/python-exec/python-exec2: `# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'chardet==2.3.0','console_scripts','chardetect' __requires__ = 'chardet==2.3.0` and I only had dev-python/chardet-2.2.1 installed, so it seems that pip somehow replaced my system's `/usr/lib/python-exec/python-exec2`. Same issue on Gentoo forums, seems to be a recurring problem with `pip`: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1006016.html